# How to Parse different Date formats from String in Java (FAQ)

Tags: datetime, locale, simpledateformat

many times I've tried to figure out how to parse different date formats. On the input we have some lines:

```
1987-03-23
null
1985-11-29
23-07-2000
17-10-1984
```

It should be translated into the Russian(As in my task, you can change it) format dd.MM.yyyy and where it does not match the pattern to draw a dash.

I decided so:

```
public class DateUtil {
public static String validDateString(String strDate) {
final List<String> dateFormats = Arrays.asList("yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd- 
yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
//Our new format
final String RU_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy";
String output = "-";
//Reviewing for all templates
for (String format : dateFormats) {
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, new Locale("ru"));
    //Do not try to analyze dates that do not match the format
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    try {
        if (sdf.parse(strDate) != null) {
            Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
            sdf.applyPattern(RU_FORMAT);
            return sdf.format(date);
        }
        break;
    } catch (ParseException e) {

    }
 }
 //Display line with a dash
 return output;
 }
}
```

Call this method you can by this line:

```
DateUtil.validDateString(input_line);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` classes are an awful sour mess of poor design. Never use them. Now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

## Parsing

First test if input string equals "null".

Next, parse the first format with simply `LocalDate.parse( "1987-03-23" )` and trap for exception. That standard ISO 8601 format is handled by default, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

Lastly, define a formatting pattern `DateTimeFormatter.ofPatten( "dd-MM-uuuu" )` and parse with that, calling `LocalDate.parse( input , formatter )`. Trap for exception.

If all those fail, you have unexpected inputs.

## Generating strings

Once you have a `LocalDate` object in hand, generate a string using `LocalDate.format` where you pass a `DateTimeFormatter`. You can define a formatting pattern as seen above. Or, you can call `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate` to let *java.time* automatically localize for you.

## Search Stack Overflow

This has been covered many many times already. Search Stack Overflow for these class names, to see more detail and more code.

I suggest using a search engine with `site:stackoverflow.com` criteria as the built-in search feature in Stack Overflow is weak and tends to ignore Answers, biasing towards only Questions.

For example, do this:

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+DateTimeFormatter&t=h_&ia=web

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).