# Validate correct date time format fetched from CSV

Tags: java, date, validation, datetime, java-8

I need to read a CSV file which has different time format in one timestamp column. It can be anything from below mentioned 5 formats. I need to match the fetched date and parse accordingly on each row.
How can I validate and parse it?

```java
public static final String DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
public static final String DEFAULT_DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
public static final String DATE_TIME_MINUTES_ONLY_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
public static final String DATE_TIME_WITHOUT_MILLIS_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
// Epoch in milli
```

Comment: Yes but here I am not creating the format. I first need to find the pattern from the input which would be any of among 5 and then need to parse it.

Comment: yes @GhostCat this data is curated from different different sources so has multiple types.

Comment: There are so many posts on SO for the same/similar requirement e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600420/datetimeformatter-accepting-multiple-dates-and-converting-to-one-java-time-libr  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587242/how-to-parse-different-date-formats-from-string-in-java-faq

Comment: Thanks @ArvindKumarAvinash. Those links helped.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a formatter with optional parts. A pattern can contain square brackets to denote an optional part, for example `HH:mm[:ss]`. The formatter then is required to parse `HH:mm`, and tries to parse the following text as `:ss`, or skips it if that fails. `yyyy-MM-dd[ HH:mm[:ss[.SSS]]]` would then be the pattern.

There is only one issue here – when you try to parse a string with the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd` (so without time part) using `LocalDateTime::parse`, it will throw a `DateTimeFormatException` with the message *Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor*. Apparently, at least one time part must be available to succeed.

Luckily, we can use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to build a pattern, instructing the formatter to use some defaults if information is missing from the parsed text. Here it is:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[ HH:mm[:ss[.SSS]]]")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
    .toFormatter();
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, formatter);
```

Tests:

```
String[] inputs = {
    "2020-10-22", // OK
    "2020-10-22 14:55", // OK
    "2020-10-22T14:55", // Fails: incorrect format
    "2020-10-22 14:55:23",
    "2020-10-22 14:55:23.9", // Fails: incorrect fraction of second
    "2020-10-22 14:55:23.91", // Fails: incorrect fraction of second
    "2020-10-22 14:55:23.917", // OK
    "2020-10-22 14:55:23.9174", // Fails: incorrect fraction of second
    "2020-10-22 14:55:23.917428511" // Fails: incorrect fraction of second 
};
```

#### And what about epoch in milli?

Well, this cannot be parsed directly by the `DateTimeFormatter`. But what's more: an epoch in milli has an implicit *timezone*: UTC. The other patterns lack a timezone. So an epoch is a fundamentally different piece of information. One thing you could do is *assume* a timezone for the inputs missing one.

However, if you nevertheless want to parse the instant, you could try to parse it as a `long` using `Long::parseLong`, and if it fails, then try to parse with the formatter. Alternatively, you could use a regular expression (like `-?\d+` or something) to try to match the instant, and if it does, then parse as instant, and if it fails, then try to parse with the abovementioned formatter.

Comment: Nice ! Good to know about `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` :)

Comment: @Eklavya Yes, I think the `DateTimeFormatter` and its builder are very powerful tools.

Answer (score 1):

The brute force approach:

- simply try your 4 formats, one after the other to parse the incoming string
- if parsing throws an exception, try the next one
- if parsing passes, well, that format just matched

Of course, if we are talking about larger tables, that is quite inefficient. Possible optimisations:

- obviously, the different patterns have subtle differences, so you could use `indexOf()` checks first. Like: if the value to be parsed contains no `':'` char, then it can only be the first pattern.
- you can look at your data manually to figure the actual distribution of patterns that are used. then you adapt the *order* of patterns to try to the likelihood of the pattern being used in your data

Alternatively: you could define your own regex. The only thing that makes it slightly ugly is the fact that your input uses month names, not month number. But I think it shouldn't be too hard to write up a single regex that covers *all* your cases.